# How to remove the first pin while dropping consecutive pins in maps in iphone?

Tags: iphone, geolocation, maps, mkpinannotationview

I am new to iphone development.I have created map applications and displayed the cuurent location and drop a pin to the current location.On clicking the button "Find Me", it drops a pin in my current location.Once again if i click the "Find Me" button it drops a pin but i am able to see the previously dropped pin in my current location. So i want to remove the previously dropped pin when i am clicking the "Find Me" button twice. Please help me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store your annotation object somewhere and when you want to remove it just call `-removeAnnotation:` method with it:

```
[mapView removeAnnotation: annotationObject];
```

Note also that if you set your map view's `showsUserLocation` property to YES it will automatically track user location using Core Location framework services and display it on the map.